# Cost of converting a pointer to a vector into a reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dereference

I am trying to access the elements of vector by using a pointer to it. I found that you can do something similar to the following:

```
std::vector<char> vector= { 'a', 'b','c','d' };
std::vector<char>* vecPointer = &vector;
std::vector<char>& vecReference = *vecPointer;
char value = vecReference[2];
```

However, I am concerned about the cost. Is this any better than just straight up dereferencing the pointer? I feel that it should be since it is becoming a reference, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There is no conversion or copy here. This is basically free.

Comment: You can always look at the compiled code to see if a reference imposes any kind of an overhead. The C++ standard does not require any specific behavior or result in this case, so the result might vary between different compilers, and likely even with different optimization compilation options with the same compiler. So, if you want to know the answer here you'll need to figure it out yourself, by looking at how your compiler compiles the above code.

Comment: If there is any cost, it will usually be incurred by the compiler (e.g. optimisiing the code to eliminate variables that are not subsequently used or needed).    Notionally, a compiler could elect to do some complex series of calculations at runtime to convert a pointer to a reference.   Practically, even when compiling without optimisations, a compiler does not need to do that because it has all the information it needs to do the conversion itself - and no modern compilers do.

Comment: You might also want to read up on the concept of "premature optimisation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go line by line.

```
std::vector<char> vector= { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
```

This seems like a cost you just have to pay, but for completeness, this is O(n) to copy the elements plus one memory allocation (which may be somewhat expensive).  If you always have 4 elements, use `std::array` to avoid the memory allocation cost.

```
std::vector<char>* vecPointer = &vector;
```

This costs nothing, you're just creating a new name for an existing thing.

```
std::vector<char>& vecReference = *vecPointer;
```

This costs nothing, same as above.

```
char value = vecReference[2];
```

This costs exactly the same as if you used `(*vecPointer)[2]` or `vector[2]`.  It should compile to a single load from an address (stored in the vector) plus an offset (2).

Of course I'm assuming you have compiler optimization enabled.  Which you must, if you care about performance at all.